# WPF Make dropdown expanded when it becomes visible

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a custom dropdown and two or more radiobuttons: when first radiobutton is ticked the dropdown is hidden, when any other is ticked the dropdown is visible and allows user to choose items (for instance, radios All Items, Selected Items, Selected Primary Items).

I need to make a dropdown expanded by default when a user clicks second or third radio (so the dropdown becomes visible and immediately becomes expanded).

I have a working approach but it doesn't seem to correspond WPF good practices:

XAML:

```
<layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit
            IsVisibleChanged="CaseTypesComboBox_OnIsVisibleChanged"
            EditValue="{Binding Path=SelectedCaseTypes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
....
/>
```

*.xaml.cs:

```
    private void CaseTypesComboBox_OnIsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cb = sender as MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit;
        cb.IsPopupOpen = cb.IsVisible;
    }
```

As you see, on event IsVisibleChanged I make the dropdown's IsPopupOpen value equal to it's visibility.

But my question is, how can I make in terms of WPF approach using Triggers/Behaviors without any additional code in *.xaml.cs file?

**Update 1:**
Here is the code of the base control style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type layoutControls:EditableMultiSelectComboBoxEdit}" 
       x:Key="{x:Type layoutControls:EditableMultiSelectComboBoxEdit}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type editors:ComboBoxEdit}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="SelectedItemDeleted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="The selected item(s) was delete. Click to refresh"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

As you see it uses some delete logic here and is based on DevExpress ComboBoxEdit control.

**Update 2:**
I've added style by this way:

```
<layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="EditableMultiSelectComboBoxEdit1" 
TargetType="layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit" />
            </layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit.Resources>
            <layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit.Style>
                <Style TargetType="layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit"
                     BasedOn="{StaticResource EditableMultiSelectComboBoxEdit1}">
```

Also tried this:

```
<layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="EditableMultiSelectComboBoxEdit1" 
TargetType="{x:Type layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit}" />
            </layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit.Resources>
            <layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit.Style>
                <Style      TargetType="layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit"
                     BasedOn="{StaticResource EditableMultiSelectComboBoxEdit1}">
```

Still getting the same error.

In the style of the base control it's key defined as

```
x:Key="{x:Type layoutControls:EditableMultiSelectComboBoxEdit}"
```

So how do I correctly inherit from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that has finally worked for me includes using of WPF Behaviors:

XAML:

```
    <layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:ComboboxExpandingBehavior/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit>
```

Behavior's code:

```
public class ComboboxExpandingBehavior : Behavior<EditableMultiSelectComboBoxEdit>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.IsVisibleChanged += OnVisibleChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.IsVisibleChanged -= OnVisibleChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void OnVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cb = sender as EditableMultiSelectComboBoxEdit;

        if (cb != null)
        {
            cb.IsPopupOpen = cb.IsVisible;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. You can accomplish this by using a `DataTrigger`, and then setting the `IsPopupOpen` property accordingly.

```
<layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit
            EditValue="{Binding Path=SelectedCaseTypes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit.Style>
        <Style TargetType="layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit">
            <Setter Property="IsPopupOpen" Value="False" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsPopupOpen" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit.Style>            
</layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit>
```

Edit:

You can also persist the base style using `BasedOn`.

```
<Style TargetType="layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyBaseStyle}">
```

where `MyBaseStyle` is a resource of the style used for the base control.

Edit2:

If you cannot create a Key from the base style, try:

```
<Style TargetType="layout:MultiSelectCaseTypeComboBoxEdit" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type editors:ComboBoxEdit}}">
```

Comment: Thank you. It is indeed expanding the dropdown, but here is what I'm getting there now: http://take.ms/qsoMJ (instead of values it just shows types and then crashes on closing). I've found that there is another style that is set for base class of all ComboBoxEdit. - probably it's the cause of a wrong behavior. I'll add it's code in the description. Is it possible to **add** the style that you suggest to the control without overwriting the style of a base control?

Comment: I've added this to the control: BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type layout:EditableMultiSelectComboBoxEdit}}" but the problem still exists. Do you have any ideas what can be the cause here?

Comment: You need to base it on a Style, not a Type.

Comment: Still not being able to make it working. I've added an update 2 with what I have tried. Could you please check it and tell what I'm doing wrong with adding style? As I see, the base style bases on Type: BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type editors:ComboBoxEdit}}" What should I do with it to make it work correctly? Thank you.

Comment: you need to reference the style as a Key, not as a Type. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do: BasedOn="{StaticResource EditableMultiSelectComboBoxEdit1}" But what if the **Key** of the **base style** contains **Type**: x:Key="{x:Type layoutControls:EditableMultiSelectComboBoxEdit}" How do I inherit from it without using of the Type keyword?

Comment: Thanks, I've finally made it working. However, it's expanding only for the first time now (if i switch it's state from Hidden to Visible it works, but if I again change it to Hidden and again to Visible it doesn't work). I've tried to modify trigger to work on both dropdown's show and hide but it didn't help either.